# @Autowired me arroja null

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data

Me encuentro con un problema que no puedo resolver. Soy bastante nuevo en spring boot y no logro solucionar un error con @Autowired.

Me arroja el error: Field userRepository in com.vueapi.services.UserDetailsServiceImpl required a bean of type 'com.vueapi.interfaces.UserRepository' that could not be found.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Tengo la entidad:

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@Table(name="user")
public class UserModel {

    @Id
    @Column
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;
    @Column
    @NotNull
    private String username;
    @Column
    @NotNull
    @JsonIgnore
    private String password;
    @Column
    @NotNull
    @JsonIgnore
    private String description;
    @Column
    @NotNull
    @JsonIgnore
    private boolean active;
     @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "users_rol", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "users_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "rol_id"))
    private Set<Rol> roles = new HashSet<>();

  public Set<Rol> getRoles() {
        return roles;
    }

    public void setRoles(Set<Rol> roles) {
        this.roles = roles;
    }

    /**
     * @return the id
     */
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    /**
     * @param id the id to set
     */
    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    /**
     * @return the name
     */
    public String getName() {
        return username;
    }

    /**
     * @param name the name to set
     */
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.username = name;
    }

    /**
     * @return the password
     */
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    /**
     * @param password the password to set
     */
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    /**
     * @return the description
     */
    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    /**
     * @param description the description to set
     */
    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    /**
     * @return the active
     */
    public boolean isActive() {
        return active;
    }

    /**
     * @param active the active to set
     */
    public void setActive(boolean active) {
        this.active = active;
    }

}
```

El metodo del controlador:

```
@RestController
public class UserController {
  
    @Autowired
    private Response response;
    @Autowired
    private JwtService jwtService;

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService;

   
   
    @RequestMapping(value = "/register", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json")
   
    public ResponseEntity<?> listUsers(@RequestBody  RegisterUserRequest userRequet) {

        return ResponseEntity.ok(userDetailsService.save(userRequet));
        
        
        /*response.setMessage("Acceso admin OK");
        response.setStatus("OK");
        return new ResponseEntity<>(response, HttpStatus.OK);*/
    }
```

}
el servicio

```
@Service

//Servicio propio para manejo de usuarios
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {
  @Autowired
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
     @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;//Error en esta linea
    @Autowired
    private RolService rolService;//Error en esta linea
    .
.
.
.
.
```

Y el repositorio

```
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<UserModel,Long>{
    public UserEntity findByNombre(String username);
}
```

Hasta donde estuve revisando tengo el @Restcontroller, @Service y hasta agregue en el repositorio el @Repository pero aun así me solicitan el bean.

Verifique no tener la creación a mano de alguna de esta clases con new y no tengo. NO comprendo que estoy haciendo mal.

Alguna idea gente ?

Edit: Agrego la clase main;

```
package com.vueapi;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class VueapiApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(VueapiApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Comment: te falto anotar la clse user repository con @Repository

Comment: Estimado como comente ya lo intente.

Comment: Según lo que veo en la documentación no agrega @repository

Comment: bueno, tines razon, Empieza por usar el constructor, el autowired fue deprecado si no mal recuerdo.
En tu clase UserService quita todas la annotaciones @Autowired y usa el constructor para pedir los 3 parametros.

`public UserDetailsServiceImpl (PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder, UserRepository userRepository, RolService rolService)`
Tambien, me podrias confirmar, tu clase main, esta en el package `com.vueapi`?

Comment: Estimado amigo ahí lo agregue de hecho esta en el com.vueapi. Al agregar en el constructor y quitar autowired me arroja " Parameter 1 of constructor in com.vueapi.services.UserDetailsServiceImpl required a bean of type 'com.vueapi.interfaces.UserRepository' that could not be found."

Comment: Has intentado hacer clean build? si usas maven, ejecuta `mvn clean build`

Comment: Si ya lo he intentado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo que el problema lo tienes en la clase 'UserEntity' a la que estas mapeando la entidad de UserModel

Podrías enseñar la clase UserEntity de la consulta de :

```
public UserEntity findByNombre(String username);
```

?

Prueba poner

```
UserModel findByNombre(String username);
```

Y si lo encapsulas con un Optional mejor.

```
Optional<UserModel> findByNombre(String username);
```

Para acceder a los datos del optional es con el metodo .get().getId(); Por ejemplo.

Comment: Estimado solucionado con lo que me comento, muchas gracias